# splitting a function inside a class

Tags: php

This is a function inside a class and it works

```
public function login($username,$password){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE password = :password AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('password' => $hashed));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION["uname"] = $row['username'];
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Now, I want to separate the above code into two functions

```
public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;  // this works
        return true;
    }   
}
```

The above code also works, but in the bellow part I cannot get the value of `$_SESSION["uname"]`

```
public function get_uname(){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE password = :password AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('password' => $hashed));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION["uname"] = $row['username'];  // this doesn't work
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are these functions called?

Comment: Hi, did you mean you are not able to get value of $row['username'].

Comment: session_start(); started?

Comment: @vaibhavmande, yes, that's it.

Comment: as a side note, are the user passwords hashed with a unique salt? what would happen if 2 users had the same password?

Comment: try echo $row['username'] have you get value? if not check your query

Comment: @serakfalcon, yes this is a separate class, named `password` and it uses unique salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simple when you take a step back and look at it.

your first function is like this:

```
public function login($username,$password){
```

note, you pass `$username`, which gets picked up by:

```
 $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);
```

in your new split function, you don't pass `$username`

```
public function get_uname(){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username); //where is username coming from?
```

so, presumably `$this->get_user_hash()` will return whatever you've programmed it to when the input is null (maybe false), and so your query is not working because `$hashed` isn't anything meaningful. Make sense?